# Powershell - Connection Occasionally Drops when Writing to SQL

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a PS Script that checks the DNS for our domain server.
The Powershell script runs every 15 minutes and usually is successful. However, occasional it fails at random with the error below but there is nothing consistent about it when it fails.

Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed
by the remote host.)"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

If I can't find the cause, I was wondering if there is a way to check for this error and automatically re-run the script?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Code Below

```
 Try
    {
    # Query DNS server, loop through each domain
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $dc -ScriptBlock `
    {
        Param($domains, $dnsserver)
        $ConnectionString = 'Data Source=MYDB; Initial Catalog=MYCAT; Integrated Security=SECURE'
        $Conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString)
        $Conn.Open()
        Foreach ($domain in $domains)
        {
            # Query specific record types
            $results = (Resolve-DnsName $domain -Server $dnsserver -Type NS)
            $results | Foreach-Object `
            {
                $name = $_.name
                $type = $_.type
                $value = $_.NameHost
                $Sql = "INSERT INTO B5_DNSCheck([DOMAIN], [TYPE], [VALUE]) VALUES('$domain','$type','$value')"
                $Cmd = $Conn.CreateCommand()
                $Cmd.CommandText = $Sql
                $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
            }
            $results = (Resolve-DnsName $domain -Server $dnsserver -Type MX)
            $results | Foreach-Object `
            {
                $name = $_.name
                $type = $_.type
                $value = $_.NameExchange
                $Sql = "INSERT INTO B5_DNSCheck([DOMAIN], [TYPE], [VALUE]) VALUES('$domain','$type','$value')"
                $Cmd = $Conn.CreateCommand()
                $Cmd.CommandText = $Sql
                $Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null
            }       
        }
    } -ArgumentList $domains, $dnsserver
        Write-Output "Completed DNS check"
    }
    catch
        {       
        Write-Output "Error with Connection"
        Stop-Transcript
        Exit 2
        }
}
Else
{
Write-Output "Error: Unable to conect to $dnsserver to check DNS at this time"
Stop-Transcript
Exit 2
}
# All done
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: If it works often enough that it's a situation where it won't fail twice in a row you could use a try/catch and just re-do the SQL command in the catch block. Else I'd do a try/catch, put it in a do/until, and make the until clause something that gets set after the SQL command successfully completes. Pseudo code: `Do{try{SQL command;$ItWorked=$true}catch{}}Until($ItWorked)`

Comment: While I was thinking of something like that,  with that error, the script still acts like it completed it successfully. I was trying to find a way to catch the error so I could have it re-run the script.

Comment: Set `$ErrorActionPreference='Stop'` before you do the SQL command. Then the try/catch should work as intended I'm pretty sure. Without you actually posting your code it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Your right. I updated my post with the code to help provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was @TheMadTechnicians advice.
Adding in $ErrorActionPreference='Stop' and a try/catch worked perfect.